# Prove that product of factorials of any given integer partition is less than the factorial of the integer?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

I believe this is true on intuition, I am just curious about the best means of proving this idea:

Given an integer $n$, then the products of the factorials of a given integer partition on $n$ (excluding $n$ itself) is less than $n!$, i.e.

$4$ has integer partitions (excluding $4$ itself):

- $3+1$
- $2+2$
- $2+1+1$
- $1+1+1+1$

It is simple to see that the product of the factorials of those integer partitions are less than $4!=24$:

- $3!\cdot 1!=6$
- $2!\cdot 2!=4$
- $2!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!=2$
- $1!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!=1$

I assume this requires the generating function?

Answer (score 2):

The proof is not too complicated. As an example, here is $2+3+4=9$.

\begin{align}
2! \cdot 3! \cdot 4!
&= (1 \cdot 2) \cdot (1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3) \cdot (1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4)\\
&\le (1 \cdot 2) \cdot (3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5) \cdot (6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9)\\
&= 9!.
\end{align}

---

Thanks to Ross Millikan for the further clarification.
The above example was intended to show how a general proof would look like.
If $a_1+\cdots+a_k = n$, then $a_1! \cdots a_k!$ is the product of $n$ integers. It is possible to increase those $n$ integers in such a way to obtain the product $n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdots n$.

Comment: I appreciate your answers. I think I should have specified that I meant in the general case...

Comment: The example indicates how to deal with the general case.  The product of the factorials of a partition has the same number of factors as the factorial of the partitioned number.  The factors are decreased, so the product is less.

Comment: Stupid question, how would you show that "If $a_1+\dots+a_k=n$ then $a_1!\dots a_k!$ is the product of $n$ integers"

Comment: @SumNeuron Write out each $a_i!$ as $a_i (a_i-1) (a_i-2) \cdots 2 \cdot 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You could generalize this specific style of proof to arbitrary partitions:

To show $n!>a!(n-a)!$ note that

$n!=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n k = \prod\limits_{k=1}^a k \cdot \prod\limits_{k=a+1}^n k > \prod\limits_{k=1}^a k \cdot \prod \limits_{k=a+1}^n (k-a) = a!(n-a)!$

The idea being that for any partition $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k)$ of $n$ you have $a_1!a_2!\cdots a_k!$ is written as the product of $n$ terms when expanded, and every term is less than or equal (*and at least one term is strictly less than so long as it is partitioned into at least two nonempty parts*) than the corresponding terms in the expansion of $n!$.

If you want to be particularly formal, you can induction on the number of parts.

Alternatively, you could use what you know about multinomial coefficients to note that

$\binom{n}{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k} = \frac{n!}{a_1!a_2!\cdots a_k!}$ is an integer implying $a_1!a_2!\cdots a_k!\leq n!$.

Comment: I appreciate your answers, the top part is not so clear so if you could maybe elaborate it, that would be appreciated. I was already aware of the multinomial coefficient, but they 1.) do not require one use up all values of $n$ - hence is not necessarily a integer partition and 2.) why I am comfortable with that the multinomial coefficient being > 0 and thus, as you stated, implying that the multinomial coefficient of an integer partition being less than or equal to $n!$, am not satisfied without a more concrete way of showing this....

Comment: @SumNeuron in fact for a multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k}$ you **do** require that $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k=n$ so yes in fact you do require that $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k)$ makes forms a partition (*though not necessarily in monotonic order*).  As for elaborating on the first part, assuming $a>0$ you have $k>k-a$ making the second product to the left of the $>$ sign strictly larger than the second product on the right of the $>$ sign.  This is the same observation that avian made, $(1\cdot 2)\cdot (3\cdot 4\cdot 5)>(1\cdot 2)\cdot (1\cdot 2\cdot 3)$

Comment: As for comparing the multinomial coefficient argument to binomial coefficient arguments, it is the exact same argument except I don't bother saying "you can partition $n$ into $r$ and $n-r$ and you can partition each of those pieces further", I go straight to the final partition $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$

Answer (score 1):

Since for $n > r$ ;$$\binom{n}{r} > 1$$

$$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} > 1$$

$$\implies n ! ~> ~r~! \times (n-r)!$$

Here $n$ and $(n-r)$ are partitions of $n$.

You can divide $r$ and $(n-r)$ further into partitions, that'll ultimately result into partitions of $n$.

$$\implies n! > a_1!~a_2!~a_3!~ \dots a_k!~~~~~~~~ \text{;  where} ~\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i=n $$